How to get the innerInstruction of a simulatedTransaction in @solana/web3.js
In the http simulateTransaction there is an innerInstruction flag. How would you be able to get the innerInstruction of a simulatedTransaction using the @solana/web3.js package? I am not seeing it in the docs https://solana-labs.github.io/solana-web3.js/types/SimulateTransactionConfig.html?

It does look like this functionality is missing in the library -- PRs are welcome to https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-web3.js to add in the flag!
